# Amazon SDK .net. Getting bucket website url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using amazon sdk for .net. With amazon S3 I am using static web hosting. I uploaded sources. I got endpoint to the static site like

```
http://[bucketname].s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

How to get bucket web site url from sdk api?

```
var client = new AmazonS3Client(apiKey, apiSecret, regionEndpoint);
```

[Here is some example but it doesn't return endpoint/url. Just document web site configuration.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ConfigWebSiteDotNet.html)

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide more information? For example, what do you mean by "bucket web site url"? Have you activated Static Website Hosting on the bucket, or do you just want the URL direct to the bucket?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API call to return that URL.

The closest is [`GetBucketWebsite()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3GetBucketWebsiteString.html) but it does not include the URL.

You can safely construct the Static Website Hosting URL from:

```
http://[bucketname].s3-website.[region].amazonaws.com
```